# Would hook_access() hide content from Views/Solr if returning FALSE?

Tags: 6, users

If I were to setup my own `hook_access()` and return `FALSE` based on a few different criteria, would this then hide the content from a view in modules like Views and Apache Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_access()` is only called when viewing/editing a *single* node. For all listings, both in core and views, you need to use the node access system. You also need to use that for node types which are not owned by your module.

Answer (score 1):

No; I tried and the Views module does not respect `hook_access()`, at least for drupal 6. Take note that I'm not sure if this is the same for you. Our site has a lot of access modules, like node access, path access, access rules, grant access, I'm not sure about the names due to the madness. With this in mind, I don't really know how `hook_access()` would behave for a clean drupal site.